# Referring to Non-Jews

Tags: gentiles, names, stackexchange, social-convention

What's the most diplomatic and politically correct way to refer to non-Jews. Both in conversation, and in terms of this site?

Comment: How about אינו יהודי?  or Aeino Yehudi?  or perhaps a Bnei Noach, if appropriate?

Comment: Goyim or shgotzim were the noms de guerre in yeshiva. They may not be too diplomatic, though.

Comment: Shkotzim isn't diplomatic, but goyim simply means gentiles in Hebrew.  It only has a negative connotation when you say it with a negative intonation.

Comment: I propose that this question be moved to meta.

Comment: @Adam Why? Is this question not about Jewish Life & Learning?

Comment: @yydl - Maybe.  However, although you asked about conversation, you also asked in terms of this site.  Maybe you could ask it a second time there?

Comment: Related: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1127

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know of a problem with "gentiles", though "non-Jews" seems equally appropriate.

Comment: "Gentiles" can be [ambiguous](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gentile#Adjective).

Comment: @WAF, Not in this context.

Comment: @IsaacMoses - Yes, but if the context is not explicit, then it can be ambiguous.

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest that the term "non-Jew" is both precise and neutral, and a perfectly acceptable halachic term as well, as halachic works such as the Shulchan Aruch often refer to א"י or אינו יהודי (non Jew).

Answer (score 0):

I think that if people are talking in English, then the words "gentile" or "non-Jew" should be used.  However, the terms gentile and non-Jew are likely to be inappropriate if the if the conversation is in more of a "[Yeshivish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yeshivish)" dialect, because these are both English words.  How about Nokhrim (נכרים) or Zarim (זרים)?  The latter terms both mean something along the lines of aliens or strangers.

Comment: How is it "inappropriate" to use sufficiently descriptive English words in an English conversation that happens to be in a "Yeshivish" context? Given that Yeshivish is entirely a folk dialect, I don't get how prescriptivism makes any sense with respect to it.