# Is Goy meant to be a pejorative term?

Tags: gentiles, words

I have never heard this word before, but the Wikipedia article insists:

> The word is also used to pejoratively describe those not of Jewish descent. It is commonly used to refer to Christians and Muslims, but is regularly used by Jews to refer to any and all peoples of faiths other than Judaism.
>
> [...]
>
> In English, the use of the word goy can be controversial. It is assigned pejoratively to non-Jews. To avoid any perceived offensive connotations, writers may use the English terms "gentile" or "non-Jew".

Looking at where the word comes from, it seems to be a benign word, equivalent with Gentile.

In common use, would Jews use this word among themselves? Is it regularly used negatively? Would they use the word among non-Jews?

---

I just noticed "goyim" in the tags, which is a word I have seem. My understanding is that would be the plural form of "goy". Is this right?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/8199/, http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1127/should-we-censor-the-term-goy-when-used-in-english-to-mean-gentile

Comment: Goyim is indeed the plural form.

Comment: It means nations

Comment: I believe the Torah refers to Jews as goyim in several places including goyim kodesh, a holy nation.

Comment: @JJLL Probably either goy kadosh or goyim kedoshim

Comment: Martin Luther painted the term as such in a polemic against Jews when he tried to evangelize and failed.

Comment: http://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/jsource/anti-semitism/Luther_on_Jews.html 6th to last paragraph

Comment: This seems to me to be [off-topic as about Jews and Hebrew, not Judaism](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1473); the only reason I'm not closing it is that a bunch of respected users other than myself have commented or answered and not voted to close. I'm [raising the issue in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/16090116#16090116) to see what people think. cc @DoubleAA

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Goy (גוֹי) is not a pejorative term. It simply means nation or member of a nation - The Jews are referred to as a Goy/Goyim on various occasions throughout the Torah. "גוי וקהל גוים" and "גוי אחד בארץ", to name just two places. In Hebrew, Goy is never used as a pejorative term. In Yiddish, it may occasionally be used pejoratively.

Comment: Part of the issue is one of intent. I can say someone is a "Jew" and it is not an insult. But if I choose the right tone/inflection, the word can indeed be insulting. The same holds true for any label.

Comment: @Danno Like when one might say they were Jewed on a deal. Likewise, Gentile might be a negative term in some circles, but if the majority use it benignly then this answer does fine.

Comment: Do you have a source for the second paragraph?

Comment: @WAF i can't locate a source or proof, so i removed it.

Answer (score 2):

the words goy means nation. so the word itself is not inherently pejorative in nature. however, in context it can be used in that manner. The same goes for the word Jew. Inherently there isn't anything wrong with it. It simple is a descriptive for someone belonging to the Jewish people. in context depending on how it is used it can become an insult

Comment: Did you add anything over user6595's answer?